# Jmeter - how to return multiple ID(s) based on the array (match JSON path with array)

Tags: jmeter

Having array as:

```
[France, Switzerland, Croatia, Spain, Brondby, Sonderjyske, CFR Cluj, Ujpest FC, Young Boys , Xamax, Bedford Town, Biggleswade Town]
```

Having JSON fetched from API call as (NOT full JSON provided)

```
{
    "payload": [
        {
            "id": 104,
            "externalId": "e5b93978-0960-4c01-a201-b15c9e6afb49",
            "shortName": "FRA",
            "name": "France",
            "countryCode": "en",
            "leagueId": 1,
            "logoUrl": "http://www.example.com/logo.png"
        },
        {
            "id": 110,
            "externalId": "7f1f76c1-483c-4c14-b5f9-61e58a5d9328",
            "shortName": "Swi",
            "name": "Switzerland",
            "countryCode": "en",
            "leagueId": 1,
            "logoUrl": "http://www.example.com/logo.png"
        },
        {
            "id": 2189,
            "externalId": "8d23300c-85f4-41b4-b0f1-65e5948f2c80",
            "shortName": "Cro",
            "name": "Croatia",
            "countryCode": "en",
            "leagueId": 1,
            "logoUrl": "http://www.sdfgsdf.com/image.png"
        }
    ],
    "errorCode": 0,
    "errorTimeStamp": null,
    "errorMessage": null,
    "hasError": false
}
```

For every single member of the array, I need to get its ID's.

I know how match for signle member using JSON path
[image]

But, how to fetch all the ID's based on the particullar array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have this "array" in a JMeter Variable called `array` you can get all the IDs by adding a [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and using the following [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) code in the "Script" area:

```
vars.get('array').replace('[', '').replace(']', '').tokenize(',').each { country ->
    def result = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).payload.find { entry -> entry.name == country.trim() }
    if (result != null) {
        log.info('Country: ' + country.trim() + ', id: ' + result.id)
    }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JsonSlurper](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)