# Jmeter - How to put each member of the forEach loop into variable

Tags: jmeter

Based on this thread - [Jmeter - how to return multiple ID(s) based on the array (match JSON path with array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68163092/jmeter-how-to-return-multiple-ids-based-on-the-array-match-json-path-with-a)

I managed to get ID's, for every single member of the array.

Now I need to alternate the code and to have a variable for every single ID.

What i tried is:

```
vars.get('array').replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(", ").each { country ->
    def result = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).payload.find { entry -> entry.name == country.trim() }
    
  vars.put("tim" +  ${__counter(,)}, result.id as String);
    
}
```

But, I am only able to get a single variable.

What should I do in order to save every single `result.id`, into variables like:

```
tim1, tim2, tim3...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't inline JMeter Functions or Variables into Groovy scripts.**

As per [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler):

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:
>
> - Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.
> - Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.
>
> When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code **as caching would only cache first replacement**. Instead use script parameters.

So I would rather recommend amending your code as follows:

```
vars.get('array').replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(", ").eachWithIndex { country, index ->
    def result = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).payload.find { entry -> entry.name == country.trim() }
    if (result != null) {
        vars.put("tim" + (index + 1), result.id as String);
    }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: thanks a lot Dmitri T. Appreciate your help!